# Laravel - Deleting/modifing ResetPasswords.php Does nothing

Tags: php, windows, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

so we are trying to modify the resetpasswords.php file found in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/ResetsPasswords.php

So when we modify it locally and test it works fine on my xampp install running windows.

When we modify it on our webserver and test it on linux. It doesn't. No matter the changes to the file nothing happens at all.

We can delete the file and the site will still work even though those functions are not there anymore.

Could use ANY advice on this.

Thank you!

Note that changing other files in the Auth dir does infact cause changes to the site on the server, it's just that one file causing issues.

Comment: tried `php artisan clear-compiled` and `composer dump-autoload` ?

Comment: Never directly modify files in the vendor folder. Look into extending them instead.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to clear the compiled class using `php artisan clear-compiled`?

By the way, you shouldn't touch any file from the vendors directory. If you try to update your dependencies, you can lose your code there.